# django-tenant-schemas wont apply migration to tenant schema, only public

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant, django-migrations

I have a multi-tenant django app using [django-tenant-schemas](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html#migrate-schemas).

There is an SiteConfig app:

**settings.py**:

```
TENANT_APPS = (
   ...
   'siteconfig',
   ...
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ...
   'siteconfig',
   ...
)
```

But my latest migration on that app won't apply to my tenants:

```py
$ ./manage.py migrate_schemas --shared
[standard:public] === Running migrate for schema public
[standard:public] Operations to perform:
[standard:public]   Apply all migrations: account, admin, ... siteconfig, sites, socialaccount, tenant, utilities
[standard:public] Running migrations:
[standard:public]   Applying siteconfig.0007_siteconfig_access_code...
[standard:public]  OK
```

As you can see it is only applying the migration to the public schema, and not my tenants.

If I look at my tenant, it shows the migration there as unapplied:

```
$ ./manage.py tenant_command showmigrations

Enter Tenant Schema ('?' to list schemas): ?
public - localhost
test - test.localhost
Enter Tenant Schema ('?' to list schemas): test
account
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_email_max_length
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add+
 .
 .
 .
siteconfig
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20200402_2201
 [X] 0003_auto_20200402_2218
 [X] 0004_auto_20200402_2233
 [X] 0005_auto_20200403_0947
 [X] 0006_auto_20200403_1528
 [ ] 0007_siteconfig_access_code  # <-- DIDN'T APPLY!
```

Why is it not applying to the tenant `test` and how can I get it to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running

```
manage.py migrate_schemas --shared
```

Which migrates only public schema

You should run

```
 manage.py migrate_schemas
```

According to [documentation](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html#migrate-schemas)